How do I evaluate JSONata expression in key in json?
I want to evaluate jsonata expression in key in AWS Step functions. I tried this:
{
  "ApplicationId": "ID",
  "SendUsersMessageRequest": {
    "MessageConfiguration": {
      "GcmMessage": {
        "Action": "OPEN_APP",
        "Title": "Order completed!",
        "SilentPush": false,
        "Sound": "default",
        "Body": "Your order is completed successfully.",
        "Data": {
          "orderId": "{% $order.id.S %}",
          "status": "COMPLETED"
        }
      }
    },
    "Users": {
      "{% $order.userId.S %}": {}
    }
  }
}

The expression {% $order.userId.S %} is not evaluated to an actual value instead I am getting it as string. How can I fix that so actual value is evaluated in the key?
Order:
{
  "order": {
    "id": {
      "S": "d7ea32bf-5dac-45a8-b924-b7752e7d8b09"
    },
    "userId": {
      "S": "11fb0540-20d1-707a-ac85-dcfbe06bad57"
    },
    "status": {
      "S": "COMPLETED"
    }
  }
}

Expected Output:
{
  "ApplicationId": "ID",
  "SendUsersMessageRequest": {
    "MessageConfiguration": {
      "GcmMessage": {
        "Action": "OPEN_APP",
        "Title": "Order completed!",
        "SilentPush": false,
        "Sound": "default",
        "Body": "Your order is completed successfully.",
        "Data": {
          "orderId": "d7ea32bf-5dac-45a8-b924-b7752e7d8b09",
          "status": "COMPLETED"
        }
      }
    },
    "Users": {
      "11fb0540-20d1-707a-ac85-dcfbe06bad57": {}
    }
  }
}


Please provide the order object.

@VladDimov Updated

Thanks, I've commented with a potential solution.

I believe you need to add a . between $ and order, like so:
"orderId": "{% $.order.id.S %}"
and
"{% $.order.userId.S %}": {}
Link to a JSONata Playground: https://jsonatastudio.com/playground/5d6a1a0b

The JSONata syntax for using it in step functions is "{% <JSONata expression> %}".

That's right. Does it work if you try this? {   "ApplicationId": "ID",   "SendUsersMessageRequest": {     "MessageConfiguration": {       "GcmMessage": {         "Action": "OPEN_APP",         "Title": "Order completed!",         "SilentPush": false,         "Sound": "default",         "Body": "Your order is completed successfully.",         "Data": {           "orderId": "{% $.order.id.S %}",           "status": "COMPLETED"         }       }     },     "Users": {       "{% $.order.userId.S %}": {}     }   } }

No, it doesn't work. Getting UNSUPPORTED_JSONATA_EXPRESSION: Reference to '$' at the top level is not supported.
